# List local chocolatey packages and order by installation date

Tags: windows, package-management, chocolatey, windows-packagemanagement

`Chocolatey` packages tend to accumulate when you have installed them long ago and have stopped using them later. I could go manually through a list of local packages

```
choco list -lo
```

But with a long list, it starts to be tedious. Is there a way to order the list by installation date? Something like

```
choco list -lo --order-by-install-date
```

I've gone through `choco list` help, but have only found ordering by popularity.

Is there any other simple of keeping track and uninstalling packages I don't need any more?

Comment: Depending on the format of the list use PowerShell or copy to another kind of program and sort the output there.

Comment: Already found a solution how to sort the output? 

Comment: Unfortunately not. Only got advice above suggesting copying the output to a different program and sorting there. I’m still surprised such a basic functionality is absent.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet of Powershell will list all installed packages (not just those managed by Choco) and order them by installed date:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Sort-Object InstallDate
```